# Join table() together in R

Tags: r

So ive been stuck with a problem in order to show the frecuencies of my groups across some data where i have multiple NA's.

Here its an example, i have dropped the Na's with the function drop_na, so they are "irrelevant" if i already got the tables.

```
df_1= data.frame(Group=c("Control","Control","Case A","Case B", "Case C"), c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

```
table(df_1$Group)
```

[image]

```
df_2= data.frame(Group=c("Control","Case A","Case A","Case B", "Case D"), c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

```
table(df_2$Group)
```

[image]

How could i join them in 1?, preferably with a column indicating its origin as "table1" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
tab <- rbind(table(df_1$Group),table(df_2$Group))
rownames(tab) <- c("table 1", "table 2")
tab

        Case A Case B Case C Control
table 1      1      1      1       2
table 2      2      1      1       1
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did try rbind, but i forgot to table the second argument :D.

Comment: great! Consider upvoting/accepting if this answered your question.